# Invoke-Command doesn't return to local machine but software is installed

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

The tl;dr: I'm puzzled as to why my script isn't returning back to the deployment machine. Does anyone have an idea why?

I was provided an EXE and a couple arguments to install some software. I'm using PowerShell's `Start-Process` to run it. The deployment machine is Win Server 2012 domain controller, logged in and being run as domain admin. The test machines are two Windows 10 Pro domained machines. All three have PS 5.1.

Being a silent install, there is no user interaction required. If I run the exact command locally, via RDP, or in a pssession, with just `c:\Software.exe /silent /arg2removed`, it installs and returns as expected.

The script runs fine up to a point. Nothing happens after `Start-Process` inside `Invoke-Command` 's `-ScriptBlock`. In a separate PowerShell window, I can use `Enter-PSSession` for each of the two client machines, and `Get-Service` and `Get-Process` both show the software's service and background processes, respectively. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on the deployment machine and get back to a prompt. No errors are reported at any time.

Here's the `Start-Process` chunk. I've read the help and it doesn't sound like I'm missing anything that would allow the ScriptBlock to finish. If I prepend `Start-Process` with `Write-Host` (like we all do), it echoes the command that would run and I get back to a command prompt on the deployment machine.

```
# Start the installer. 
Start-Process `
    -FilePath "C:\${using:SrcExe}" `
    -ArgumentList "/SILENT", "/arg2removed" `
    -WorkingDirectory C:\ `
    -Wait `
    -Verbose `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
    -ErrorVariable InstallErrors
```

Here's most of the script. The only items before `Invoke-Command` are where I set up `$ComputersToInstallOn`, enter the credentials (yes I'm sure they're correct), and supply the path to the EXE.

```
Invoke-Command `
    -ComputerName $ComputersToInstallOn `
    -Credential $Creds `
    -Verbose `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
    -ErrorVariable InvokeCommErrors `
    -ScriptBlock {
        # Get and print the destination machine's hostname
        $ThisMachine = Get-Content Env:\COMPUTERNAME ; $ThisMachine

        # Print the current date and time
        Get-Date

        # Check if Sentinel processes are running. If not, assume it's not installed.
        $S1Procs = get-process sentinel*

        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($S1Procs)) {
            # Sentinel isn't installed. Continue.

            # Map a drive letter to $SrcFolder. Not theoretically necessary but Start-Process complains when copying with the UNC path directly.
            New-PSDrive `
                -Name S `
                -PSProvider FileSystem `
                -Credential ${using:Creds} `
                -Root ${using:SrcFolder} `
                -verbose

            # List remote folder
            Get-ChildItem S:\

            # Copy the $SrcExe to C:\
            Copy-Item `
                -Path "S:\${using:SrcExe}" `
                -Destination C:\ `
                -Verbose `
                -ErrorAction Stop `
                -ErrorVariable CopyErrors

            # Unmount drive
            Remove-PSDrive S -verbose

            # Verify EXE exists locally
            Get-ChildItem -Path C:\${using:SrcExe}

            # If there were copy errors, abort.
            if ($CopyErrors) {
                Write-Host "There was an error copying '${using:SrcExe}' to $ThisMachine. Aborting."
                exit 1 } else {
                # All good so far. Continue to install.

                Write-Host "$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') : Starting install on ${ThisMachine}. You may need to Ctrl+C to return to the local machine. Check processes on each machine though."

                # Start the installer. 
                Start-Process `
                    -FilePath "C:\${using:SrcExe}" `
                    -ArgumentList "/SILENT", "/arg2removed" `
                    -WorkingDirectory C:\ `
                    -Wait `
                    -Verbose `
                    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
                    -ErrorVariable InstallErrors

                # ScriptBlock doesn't seem to make it to anything after Start-Process.

                # Remove the EXE.
                Remove-Item "C:\${using:SrcExe}" -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                exit 0
                # Get-Process -Name Sentinel*
                # echo "Sleeping. Now would be the time to abort."
                # Start-Sleep 15
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "Sentinel appears to be installed and running."
            $S1Procs
            Get-Service -Name Sentinel* | Where-Object { $_.Status -match "Running" }
            exit 0
        }
    }
if($InvokeCommErrors){
    Write-Host "There were some errors."
}
```

**EDIT**: Added some requested info.

Comment: as an aside, please take a look at `Get-Help about_Splatting` for ways to avoid those nasty backticks.

Comment: what you describe sounds like the installer is expecting some sort of response. have you confirmed that the installer DOES NOT require any user interaction at all?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey , I've used splatting. I forgot about it in this case. That would've made it easier to read on here with the highlighting. "arg1removed" is actually "/SILENT". There is no user interaction required. If I run the exact command, with just `c:\Software.exe /silent /arg2remove` in a pssession, it works and returns as expected.`

Comment: [1] PLEASE add that info to your Question so that others can find it. [2] does the installer need to run in an interactive session? your `Invoke-Command` will run in a _non-interactive_ session.